# MQL4: OrderModify() always gets 130 response

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I want my EA to modify an order automatically, to put a StopLoss once in a profit state, but why it always error?

I already get the minimum point level as well, but it did not give me any luck.

Here is the vars

```
        double _stopLevelTimes = 1.5;
        int     StopLevel      = (int) ( miStopLevel + miSpread );
```

What I want is to make the stop level 1.5 times higher then the minimum stop loss points level and I already add the spread too.

Those vars are filled automatically from brokers.

```
        if (  OrderType()      == 0
           && OrderOpenPrice() >  OrderStopLoss()
              ){
              _stopLoss   = NormalizeDouble( OrderOpenPrice()
                                           + ( Point() * (  StopLevel
                                                         * _stopLevelTimes
                                                           )
                                               ),
                                             miDigits
                                             );
              _clr        = clrBlue;
              RefreshRates();
              modified    = OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                                         OrderOpenPrice(),
                                         _stopLoss,
                                         OrderTakeProfit(), 0, _clr );
        }
        else
        if (  OrderType()      == 1
           && OrderOpenPrice() <  OrderStopLoss()
              ){  
              _stopLoss   = NormalizeDouble( OrderOpenPrice()
                                           - ( Point() * (  StopLevel
                                                         * _stopLevelTimes
                                                           )
                                               ),
                                             miDigits
                                             );
              _clr        = clrRed;
              RefreshRates();
              modified    = OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                                         OrderOpenPrice(),
                                         _stopLoss,
                                         OrderTakeProfit(), 0, _clr );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even *( IT Manager at Forex Falcon  )* ought know a few hard facts:

- Every MQL4 code has transferred several responsibilities to code-designers, submitting a mandatory **`OrderSelect()`** before any db.Pool-operations. Not because of the db.Pool-SELECT-free mode of operations in the `OrderModify()`, but because your code compares db.Pool-record-values ( and such record must be first explicitly SELECT-ed )
- There are more values to monitor, than just a `Spread` and a `StopLevel`. There could be a third reason for **`Error_130`**, once your code requests MT4-Server side to modify an Order, which fortunately remains inside a **`FreezeLevel`** zones, setup by your Broker's **[ Terms and Conditions ]**. Be sure to re-read them, as they rule all your XTO/non-XTO.
- Last but not least, your belief will get shattered, as both the StopLevel, FreezeLevel and Spread need not be constant and both Brokers and MetaQuotes MQL4 Documentation warns about situations, when returned values ought be understood not as a value, but as an indication about actually not having a value to work with, but to flag **floating ( unknown ) values**.

### Best next step?

In all cases, log both actual and requested new values, into a file and check, if these meet the Broker published rules in [Terms and Condition ].

If not, reconcile any such documented non-conformities with Broker representative and your local FSA-authority.

Comment: Yes I already put the Orderselect outside the code i provided, but the important thing is the OrderModify.

Well this is my first time for making a EA.

Ah i see, thanks for the info! it gives me a something in the head, and I think I know what to do now

Answer (score 0):

You just check that in case of long, your stoploss is below `OrderOpenPrice()`, and compute the new stop loss. but you do not know whether the current price is far enough from the current price. it can be the case that your current price to close the order (`OrderClosePrice()`, `Bid` for long) is below the new stop loss, in such case modification is not possible. after that, make sure that you allow `STOP_LEVEL * Point` distance from current price to the new stop loss.